# React-Redux. How can I get the redux result values to be passed through setState

Tags: reactjs, redux

**React-Redux.** How can I get the redux result values to be passed through setState. I know this question may have been asked before
but most solution I found here could not resolve my problem.

The Code below displays records from JSON file

```
[{"id":"1","firstName":"jmarkatti","lastName":"john"}]
```

The code below shows how am able to display the result **without map()** function within the render() method and it works fine.

```
Last Name: {pgs1.items1 &&  this.props.pgs1.items1[0].lastName}<br />
First Name: {pgs1.items1 &&  this.props.pgs1.items1[0].lastName}<br />
```

The code below shows how am able to display the result with **map()** function within the render() method which also works fine.

```
    {pgs1.items1 && pgs1.items1.map((pg1, i) =>


                            <li key={pg1.id}>
{pg1.firstName} -- {pg1.lastName}

</li>
 )}
```

Now I have requirements of passing the redux results values in a **setState()** method and then alert the values. For this I have
tried the following codes below

```
 componentWillMount() {
this.props.dispatch(userActions.getAll_Rec());

 this.setState({
      lastName:  this.props.pgs1.items1 && this.props.pgs1.items1[0].lastName,
      firstName: this.props.pgs1.items1 && this.props.pgs1.items1[0].firstName,
    });
alert(lastName);
alert(firstName);

    }

or


componentWillReceiveProps(props) {
  this.setState({
      lastName: props.items1[0].lastName,
      firstName: props.items1[0].firstName,
    });
alert(lastName);
alert(firstName);
                }
```

But it shows error

**ReferenceError: lastName is not defined
  at Paging1.componentWillMount** it seems the JSON file for lastName and firstName is not properly accessed.

**Here is the redux Code**

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

import {UActions } from '../actions';

class Paging1 extends React.Component {



constructor(props) {
        super(props);
this.state = {
id: '',
lastName: '',
firstName: '',   
        };

    }




   // componentDidMount() {

    componentWillMount() {
this.props.dispatch(userActions.getAll_Rec());

    }


/*
i have tried 


 componentWillMount() {
this.props.dispatch(userActions.getAll_Rec());

 this.setState({
      lastName:  this.props.pgs1.items1 && this.props.pgs1.items1[0].lastName,
      firstName: this.props.pgs1.items1 && this.props.pgs1.items1[0].firstName,
    });
alert(lastName);
alert(firstName);

    }

or 


componentWillReceiveProps(props) {
  this.setState({
      lastName: props.items1[0].lastName,
      firstName: props.items1[0].firstName,
    });
alert(lastName);
alert(firstName);
                }

*/



    render() {



        const { pg1, pgs1 } = this.props;


        return (


 <div className="list">
                <div className="res">

Last Name: {pgs1.items1 &&  this.props.pgs1.items1[0].lastName}<br />
First Name: {pgs1.items1 &&  this.props.pgs1.items1[0].lastName}<br />



            </div>



</div>

        );
    }
}


function mapStateToProps(state) {
    const { pgs1} = state;
    const { pg1 } = state;
    return {
        pg1,
        pgs1
    };
}


const connectedPaging1 = connect(mapStateToProps)(Paging1);
export { connectedPaging1 as Paging1 };
```

**Here is the Reducer file**

```
import { userConstants } from '../_constants';

export function pgs1(state = {}, action) {
  switch (action.type) {


case userConstants.GETALL_REQUEST:
  return {
    ...state,
    loading: true
  };
case userConstants.GETALL_SUCCESS:
  return {
    loading: false,
    error: null,
items1: action.pgs1
  };
```

Comment: Could you please reformat the code so it's easier to see what you're actually doing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Passing the **redux** resultant records via **componentWillReceiveProps()** functions solves the issue.

Thanks all

```
componentWillReceiveProps(props) {


  this.setState({
      lastName: props.pgs1.items1 && props.pgs1.items1[0].lastName,
      firstName: props.pgs1.items1 && props.pgs1.items1[0].firstName,
    });
}
```